# Как я могу использовать for_in для запроса API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, requests

Я имею в виду, что у меня есть код:

```swift
import UIKit

var ipName = ["192.168.1.0"..."192.168.1.254"]
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.1/")!)
for i in ipName {
    print("It's, \(i)")
}
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
    data, response, error in
    print(String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self))
    print(response)
    print(error)
}
task.resume()
```

и мне нужно запросить все адреса из моей сети и выбрать всех, кто подключен ("например" из 254 адресов). Я хочу получить ответы всех 254-х запросов и из них что бы было выделенно (любым образом) те которые подключенны к моему вай фаю прямо сейчас.

Comment: В чём в конечном итоге заключается вопрос?

Comment: Вы об этом "Я хочу получить ответы всех 254-х запросов и из них что бы было выделенно (любым образом) те которые подключенны к моему вай фаю прямо сейчас."

Comment: Вот мне предоставили ответ с StackOverflow(английского): let ipRange = 0...254
for i in ipRange {
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.\(i)")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No readable string")
    }
    task.resume()
}

Comment: Но после того как он находит мои подключения к вай фаю он продолжает присылать мне ответы с другим статус кодом. Если вы знаете/можете помочь дополнить код, я буду при много благодарен вам!